# How to force a Connect event update from Docusign to Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I had a SF userid go expired and I've got a bunch of envelopes that need to be updated with the appropriate status.  I send out envelopes via the api.  Then I programmatically create the dsfs__DocuSign_Status__c including the evelope id and AccountID/Company.  As soon as Docusign gets sends the envelope it updates the dsfs__DocuSign_Status__c  record and creates the    dsfs__DocuSign_Recipient_Status__c records.  All this works great.  My issue is my SF ID's password expired and I have 100s of missing dsfs__DocuSign_Recipient_Status__c records.  How can I force an update from DS?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can force DocuSign Connect (webhook) updates to be re-sent, however you can only do it if you are a member of the sending account.  For instance, if a given account member has DocuSign Connect configured, and they send a signature request through Salesforce using their DocuSign account, then they can re-publish those updates through their account settings.

To re-send DocuSign Connect updates:

1. Login to your sandbox or DocuSign account and in the top right profile drop down select **"Go to the Admin"**.
2. Under the Integrations section on left select **"Connect"**.
3. Click the **LOGS** button at the top of the connect configuration screen.
4. On a given connect log click the **REPUBLISH** button to re-send the update.